# Stripe integration with iOS: Saving and referencing saved cards

Tags: swift, xcode, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, swift5

I'm trying to make an app that sells a service, for which users pay based on the amount of time they've used it for, so I don't have a physical shipping address involved.

I want to be able to allow my users to save and then reference saved cards in future transactions. I know the way Stripe tracks a specific customer is through a `customer_id`, but I'm not sure how to attach a card to a specific `customer_id` and then reference it in future.

Also, I'm a little confused on the use of `ephemeral_keys`. Some Stripe tutorials talk about needing these on the server side, and some don't mention them at all, and that leaves me very confused.

This one talks about `ephemeral_keys` while creating a `paymentIntent`: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic#

And this one doesn't: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if you need any more information from me.

PS: If you could also point me to some of the relevant View Controllers Stripe uses to save new cards and display saved cards, I'd be more than grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flow on https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic includes the Customer for your payment context, which will cause the created PaymentMethod to be attached to that Customer. You can verify this after the initial payment by retrieving the PaymentMethod on your backend with your secret key and checking its `customer` field [0].

If you have a PaymentMethod and want to attach it to a Customer, you'd use the API on the backend [1].

You can retrieve a list of the Customer's existing PaymentMethods via the API [2] on the backed as well (again, with your secret key). Then you can pass a list of their id's and some identifying feature (last 4 digits, as an example) to your app in order to display and let the customer select the one they want to use. Then you take that PaymentMethod's 'id' and use it to create the new payment.

Ephemeral keys are usually only used with the iOS (or Android) SDK's, so when you're using the backend of your integration (i.e. the part that is running on a server somewhere and not distributed with your app) you generally don't need to worry about them.

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/retrieve

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/attach

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/list